# SCSS syntax for nesting child selector using '&' with space?

Tags: sass

Both of the following selectors result in the same output from SCSS: is there a common stardard that is used which would mean one is preferred over the other?

I don't know if this is based on person preference, or if there is a genuine practical reason to use one over the other

```
// Example 1
div {
    & li:hover a {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}
// Example 2
div {
    li:hover a {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
}

// Output
div li:hover a {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: `& selector` is pointless, surely? `&` is generally used when you want to do something that *can't* be done be nesting alone.

Comment: The & is used for referencing parent selectors take a look at http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#Referencing_Parent_Selectors_____parent-selector

Comment: Will best be used for refrencing the parent, child elements are already nested so using & just seems redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good practice is to use `&` sign when you have multiple `classes` on `elements` or you have elements with custom `classes`, like `title-thin`, `title-bold`, `title-regular`, where you will use the following `syntax`:

```
.title{
   &-thin{
     ... 
   }
   &-bold{
     ... 
   }
   &-regular{
     ...
   }
}
```

For the child elements don't use the `&` operator. There could be some misunderstandings from some developers which could join the project.

Technically you can use the `&` with space to style the child elements, but for architecture is not good.